# Laravel eager loading use parents column value

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my scenario, I have 2 table `Product` and `Rack`. They have many to many relationship, so there is a pivot table ( `History` Class ) to connect them .

**Tables**

This is our **Products** table:

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product A |
| 2 | Product B |
| 3 | Product C |

**Rack** table:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X1 |
| 2 | Y2 |
| 3 | Z3 |

**History** table:

| product_id | rack_id | historyable_id | historyable_type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | X1 | 1 | Receive | 10 |
| Product A | Y1 | 1 | Receive | 5 |
| Product A | X1 | 1 | Delivery | 2 |
| Product B | X1 | 2 | Receive | 10 |

I want to get list like this:

| product_id | rack_id | historyable_id | historyable_type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | X1 | 1 | Receive | 8 |
| Product A | Y1 | 1 | Receive | 5 |
| Product B | X1 | 2 | Receive | 10 |

If type `receive` is 'debit' and **delivery** is 'credit' to calculate quantity, and i have two unique column in here `product_id` and `rack_id`.

Here is my method right now:

```
public function collection()
    {
        $products = Product::with('racks')->get();

        $results = collect();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            foreach ($product->racks as $rack) {
                $rackWithHistory = $rack->load(['history' => function ($q) use ($product) {
                    return $q->where('product_id', $product->id)->with('histories:id');
                }]);

                $results->push([
                    'product_name'          => $product->name,
                    'product_description'   => $product->description,
                    'location'              => $rack->code,
                    'quantity'              => $rack->getQuantity($rackWithHistory->history)
                ]);
            }
        }

       return $result;
    }
```

It works but in large data (try in 2000rows) that takes a very long time, and always touch
`php - Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted` can you guys give me some tips so it can load faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try chunking the data

```
Product::with('racks')->chunk(100, function ($products) use($results) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        foreach ($product->racks as $rack) {
            $rackWithHistory = $rack->load(['history' => function ($q) use ($product) {
                return $q->where('product_id', $product->id)->with('histories:id');
            }]);

            $results->push([
                'product_name'          => $product->name,
                'product_description'   => $product->description,
                'location'              => $rack->code,
                'quantity'              => $rack->getQuantity($rackWithHistory->history)
            ]);
        }
    }
});
```

When you chunk data, you only take a x amount of items at a time. In your case 100 items at a time.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#chunking-results